# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mailer

I'm using Rails 3.2, and when I try using `UserMailer` to send an email, it gives me the error:

```
"Errno::ECONNREFUSED (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2))"
```

on this line:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

This is the `create` function the email is supposed to be delivered in:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  I'm pretty sure I've been able to send emails fine before.

Comment: Are you using http://mailcatcher.me/?

Comment: no, I tested it on a different site I used successfully before and it was fine, I'm using gmail as my SMTP server and the database is hosted on my local machine.  I'm using ActionMailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it seems I forgot to add setup_mail.rb under config/initializers.